# is there a way to filter out the css style attributes that are marked with strikethrough?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to filter out the css style attributes that are marked with strikethrough?  I want a clean view of the styles that are being applied without the extraneous style attributes that are not being applied. This will make it easier for me to sort through the style info for a page.

Comment: could you please be specific how/what exactly you want to achieve? Do you want to use JavaScript? Do you want a CSS-Selector which shows you elements with inline styling having a strikethrough?

Answer (score 1):

Try "computed" tab in the dev tools. It'll show you the cumulative effect of styles being applied to an element and you can expand from there.